# SQL query date column sorting issue

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am writing a SQL query which will return data of customer bills payments.

We have these payments in two different tables, one is "Bills" and other is "receipts". When my query data it shows that "receipts data" (from receipts table) in ascending order. I have two more date columns to show in result set which are "bill month" and "due date" (from bills table). When I try to apply order by on any of these mentioned columns it shows wrong data. Please help.

My query is attached below. thank you.

```
select distinct
     bil.bill_id as Bill#,  --(bill), this table has bill month and due date column
     rec.receiptid as IDs,  --(receipts),this table has receipt payment date,amount
     sp.spaceno as spaceno,-- (space), this table has property names
     lo.description as locaiton,-- (location),this table has details of property
     one.name as owner_name,-- (owner), this table has owners information
     bt.billtype as Particular,--(billtype),where bill types are saved
     rec.rdate as Date,-- this column of receipt table showing wrong date   data 
     dc.dr as opening,-- (DCnotes), this table has total payable amount column
     rec.amount as dr,-- this column tells the paid amount
     bil.amount as cr,-- this columen tell the payable amount
     bil.balamount as balance,-- this column tells the net total of dr-cr columns
     bil.billmonth as BillMonth,-- bill month column from bill table
     bil.duedate as DueDate -- bill due date column from bill table
from 
    bills bil
inner join 
    Owners one on bil.ownerid = one.ownerid
inner join 
    Receipts rec on bil.spaceid = rec.propertyid
inner join 
    DCnotes dc on bil.spaceid = dc.property
inner join 
    BillTypes bt on bil.billtypeid = bt.billtypeid
inner join  
    Spaces sp on bil.spaceid = sp.spaceid
inner join 
    Locations lo on sp.locationid = lo.locationid
where 
    bil.siteid = '15'
```

This is the image of SQL query result:

[image]

This is the image of required data in report:

[image]

Please check attached images of required data and SQL query result

Comment: Hey man, can you give us some data example that way we can help you faster

Comment: Please check attached images of required data and sql query result

Comment: `ORDER BY bil.DueDate`?

Comment: What do you mean by "wrong data"?

Comment: As @RaduGheorghiu mentions, did you add the ORDER BY column? without that, you are not guaranteed sorted results.

Comment: problem solved guys. thank you